# Change a linear map matrix representation $M$ to $-M$

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Sorry basic question with regards to change of basis. Just trying get a better understanding of the mechanics.

If I have a linear map, $\phi : V \rightarrow V$ where v has basis $v_1,...v_n$ and $M$ is the matrix representation of this map.

If I then change my basis to $-v_1,...,-v_n$, will the matrix representation of my linear map become $-M$.
If not, what will need to do with my basis.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: The matrix will not change - this follows from the definition of the matrix of a linear operator.

Comment: Why not check out for yourself the case $n=1$ and $\phi: v\mapsto 3v$?

Comment: @ben As others have said, your change of basis does not have this effect. For most matrices $M$, there is no change of basis to get from $M$ to $-M$ (i.e. $M$ and $-M$ are not "similar"). If you're looking for a general procedure to find such a change of basis, the easiest approach would probably be to start with Jordan form or something along those lines.